# logstash not mapping to values in indices

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, grok

I have a sample log

```
2016-12-28 16:40:53.290 [debug] <0.545.0> <<"{\"user_id\”:\”79\”,\”timestamp\":\"2016-12-28T11:10:26Z\",\"operation\":\"ver3 - Requested for recommended,verified handle information\",\"data\":\"\",\"content_id\":\"\",\"channel_id\":\"\"}">>
```

for which I have written a logstash grok filter

```
filter{
    grok {
       match => { "message" => "%{URIHOST} %{TIME} %{SYSLOG5424SD} <%{BASE16FLOAT}.0> <<%{QS}>>"}
    }
}
```

in http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ everything is working fine and values are getting mapped with filter.

When I am pushing values with this filter into elastic search it's not getting mapped and in message only I am getting whole log as it is.

[image: please refer image for values I am getting in elastic search , it's kibana screen shot]

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: if you could show us the whole config? Your `grok` matching seems to be fine.

Comment: Don't use URIHOST to match the date; you'll only confuse the next person who has to maintain your config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your kibana screen shot isn't loading, but I'll take a guess: you're capturing patterns, but not *naming* the data into fields.  Here's the difference:

```
%{TIME}
```

will look for that pattern in your data.  The debugger will show "TIME" as having been parsed, but logstash won't create a field without being asked.

```
%{TIME:myTime}
```

will create the field (and you can see it working in the debugger).

You would need to do this for any matched pattern that you would like to save.

Comment: still not creating any field I have change everything but still it's the same. :(

Comment: It's basically same .. like I am removing filter so it's coming same .. one thing to notice is in debugger it's working fine while matching the values but while parsing data it is giving tags as :

     "beats_input_codec_plain_applied, _grokparsefailure"

and when I am removing the filter is is not giving _grokparsefailure tag.

now I know there is parsing error but debugger is showing mapped values correctly but in logstash it's throwing error.

Comment: input {
    beats {
        port => "5043"
    }
}
filter{
        grok {
           match => { "messege" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp_match} %{SYSLOG5424SD:logtype} <%{BASE16FLOAT:processid}.0> <<%{QS:mydata}>>"}
        }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    }
}

Comment: even when my sample input is 

<<"{\"user_id\":\"79\",\timestamp\":\"2016-12-28T11:10:26Z\",\"operation\":\"ver3 - Requested for recommended,verified handle information\",\"data\":\"\",\"content_id\":\"\",\"channel_id\":\"\"}">>

and config is

input {
    beats {
        port => "5043"
    }
}
filter{
        grok {
           match => { "messege" => "<<%{QS:mydata}>>"}
        }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    }
}


still it is tagging as grokparsefailure